# Selenium: No test available. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

Tried to create CI build in Azure DevOps. But getting the below message.

No test available in C:\agent...\bin\DEV\projectname.dll
Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I have used C# in Visual Studio, with NUnit version="3.12.0". NUnit 3 Test adapter 3.16.1.
It's working fine in my local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it could run successfully on your local Visual Studio (contains NUnit 3 Test adapter 3.16.1).

You could try to add this package (NUnit3TestAdapter -Version 3.16.1) to your project. Then this package will be added when you build this project.

For example:

Package.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
....
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.16.1" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Or xxx.csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
...
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

You could check if it could work after adding this package reference.

On the other hand, the test Plantform version seems to affect this test.

You could set the test plantform is `X64` in the `Visual Studio Test Task`.

[image: Task Settings]

Here is a Blog about [the detailed troubleshooting steps](http://hermit.no/how-to-resolve-cases-of-visual-studio-no-tests-appearing/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked after adding NUnit3 adapter